# Can't put a Cache from generated excelfile Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, caching, windows-10, phpspreadsheet

hope you are doing well

I'm having the problem with Laravel Cache
First , this only happened on my produyction server (Windows 10 Server)

It seems that the apps can't i put a Cache which comming from PHPSpreadsheet Excel Object.
I already tried it with array or php objects, and they are all fine

```
Cache::put($cacheKey, $spreadsheet, now()->addMinutes(2));
```

Cache setting :

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],
```

I assume if i can put thearray and php object , then there is nothing wrong with the folder permission.

How to solve this ?